jOOQ: How to map Record with projection Fields into POJO
I am performing a select query with a dynamic list of columns (projection).
final var columns = List.of(...); // List of columns I want, based on REST request parameters.
dsl.select(columns).from(TABLE_1).join(TABLE_2).on(...)...

The result are Records containing a subset of Fields from the joined tables. I want to map them to DTOs, leaving properties for missing Fields as null.
public record ElementDto(
    @Nullable T property1,
    @Nullable T property2,
    @Nullable T property3,
...
    @Nullable T propertyN
) {}

Some DTO property names differ from the Field names in the database. If possible, I want to avoid annotating the DTO with hardcoded column names to maintain type safety and to protect against schema changes.
I tried using an ad-hoc RecordMapper like this:
map(record -> new ElementDto(
    record.get(TABLE_1.FIELD_1),
    record.get(TABLE_1.FIELD_2),
    record.get(TABLE_1.FIELD_3),
...
    record.get(TABLE_2.FIELD_N)
))

The problem is that the Record.get(Field) method throws an exception if the Field is not present in the Record. What I'm missing are Record.getOptional(Field) or Record.get(Field, defaultValue) methods.
I also checked the Record.into(Class) method, which uses DefaultRecordMapper to match Field names with property names in the DTO constructor using reflection. However, in my case, some DTO properties have different names.
What is the jOOQ way of accomplishing this mapping task?


What I'm missing are Record.getOptional(Field) or Record.get(Field, defaultValue) methods.

Why not write a 1 liner utility yourself?
static <T> T getOptional(Record r, Field<T> field) {
    return r.field(field) != null ? r.get(field) : null;
}

